# Keeping `__pycache__` out of my repository when adding/committing from pythonanywhere

Tags: git, pythonanywhere

I built a web app on a my local win7 machine.  I did it with pycharm and used git as version control.  I'm a total git novice.

I put the repository on github so that I could stage the webapp to my pythonanywhere server.

On pythonanywhere side, I did some small edits to various files. I wanted to commit these changes back to the repository.

```
(udemy) 10:44 ~/keystone (master)$ git commit -m "got it running on pythonanywhere staging"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   keystone/settings/base.py
        modified:   keystone/settings/local_postgres.py
        modified:   keystone/settings/staging_straits.py
        deleted:    p0150_1.pdf
Untracked files:
        crapboard/__pycache__/
        crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/
        crapboard/templatetags/__pycache__/
        keystone/__pycache__/
        keystone/settings/__pycache__/
no changes added to commit
```

There were three modified files and one deletion that I wanted to commit to the repository.

so I did

```
(udemy) 14:03 ~/keystone (master)$ git add --all
(udemy) 14:03 ~/keystone (master)$ git commit -m "staged to pythonanywhere"
[master ac6bb7e] staged to pythonanywhere
 27 files changed, 23 insertions(+), 115 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/admin.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/apps.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/forms.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/models.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/pdf_views.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/urls.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/__pycache__/views.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/0001_squashed_0005_auto_20170921_2154.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/0002_auto_20170909_1137.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/0003_auto_20170912_2029.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/0004_problem_author.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/0005_auto_20170921_2154.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/templatetags/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 crapboard/templatetags/__pycache__/crapboard_filters.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 keystone/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 keystone/__pycache__/urls.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 keystone/settings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 keystone/settings/__pycache__/base.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 keystone/settings/__pycache__/settings_secret.cpython-36.pyc
 create mode 100644 keystone/settings/__pycache__/staging_straits.cpython-36.pyc
 rewrite keystone/settings/staging_straits.py (65%)
 delete mode 100644 p0150_1.pdf
```

Argh. It committed all these `__pycache__` directories too.

I'm guessing this happened because I should have made some kind of global/general .gitignore file on my pythonanywhere server?

So questions:

1) how do I get rid of this **pycache** stuff from my repository permanently
2) how do I prevent my pythonanywhere server from trying to add that stuff to my repository in the future -- I do not have this issue with pycharm/local machine -- it ignores those files.

Comment: Some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository (You probably already have a .gitignore file somewhere in your dir)

Comment: On part (1): note that you cannot *change* any existing commits, but you can stop using them, and eventually, if there's no way to find them, they expire. If you have not *sent* this new commit anywhere else (so that only you have it), you can stop using this commit (by using `git commit --amend` to shove it aside, or `git reset` to hide it away so that even you can't see it). Then you won't have `__pycache__` in any of your (visible) commits, so that you won't send commits that have it on to any other repository either.

Comment: Put it in .gitignore

Comment: After adjust gitignore, I had to do this  for every file, so I call awk for help: "git status | grep pycache | awk {'print $3'} | xargs git reset HEAD"

Answer (score 45):

According to [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), it is simplely to add to ~/.gitignore the following:

```
**/__pycache__
```

> A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
>   example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same
>   as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar"
>   anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".

Comment: my bad, my folder was being tracked already thts why it didnt work

Answer (score 4):

1. You could do a `git rm` to delete the folder, then commit and push that. Or if you are feeling super adventurous and nobody else uses your repo, you could do a `commit --fixup` and then a `rebase --interactive` to clean everything up. See [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/autosquashing-git-commits) for details.
2. Add `__pycache__` to `~/.gitignore`. Or better yet just checkin a .gitignore file for your repo.